# Clear newlines and all unnecessary whitespaces in xml tags

Tags: php, regex, xml

**I need all XML tags to fit on one line (*ie* clear newlines)**; if possible, I'd like to clear all other unnecessary whitespaces, but it's less important.

*The reason why I need this clearing is:

I'm using a `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` to validate an XML against an XSD schema. The function returns errors with line numbers, and these line numbers don't match the ones numbered in the editor in which I display the results (because the validator ignores the newlines in the tags, and the editor doesn't).*

I found a lot of questions and answers about matching a string between two specific delimiters using regexp, but not for matching **some** specific characters between the two delimiters. The nearest I found is: [Remove whitespace from XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915330/remove-whitespace-from-xml-tags) but I was not able to bring this to work in php.

**Example:** given the string:

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" 
    version=""
    unique-identifier=""
    prefix="optional"
    lang="optional"
    dir="optional"
    id="optional"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf http://fpierrat.fr/mvs/epub3-opf.xsd"
>
```

I need to delete all newlines (and if possible all extra-tabs and extra-spaces) between tagnames and attributes. Output should look like:

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="" unique-identifier="" prefix="optional" lang="optional" dir="optional" id="optional" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf http://fpierrat.fr/mvs/epub3-opf.xsd" >
```

**Only the whitespaces between the enclosing `<`and `>` should be affected.** Tag content should remain as is.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, just use [DOMDocument::saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php).

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
    version=""
    unique-identifier=""
    prefix="optional"
    lang="optional"
    dir="optional"
    id="optional"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf http://fpierrat.fr/mvs/epub3-opf.xsd"
>
<foo>
    look at my
    fancy
    whitespace
</foo>         <bar/>
</package>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="" unique-identifier="" prefix="optional" lang="optional" dir="optional" id="optional" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf http://fpierrat.fr/mvs/epub3-opf.xsd">
<foo>
    look at my
    fancy
    whitespace
</foo>         <bar/>
</package>
```

Comment: You're right... that's what I'm doing for displaying in the editor, I mis-analysed the line-number differences: the newlines are deleted in my editor, it's in the errors returns that `schemaValidate()` actually DOES take them in account. So what should I do, `$dom->loadXml($source)`, then `$tmp=$dom->saveXml()` and again `$dom->loadXml($tmp)` so that `$dom->schemaValidate()` works on a "clean" source ? sound weird... But I found no option for `loadXml()` to ignore these newlines.

Comment: I just added this variable to insist on the 3 needed actions